# Looking for a potential method to compare two values not knowing whether it is a string or any other class

Tags: c++, overloading

I am looking for a way to implement my code so that the generic function below can take in any type of variable, but when it takes in a string it will compare 2 strings using the function below and when it takes any other type of variable, it will simply use the normal comparison operators. I am attempted to use function overloading to accomplish as you can see:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "binaryTreeInterface.h" // Overloading the functions here FYI

using namespace std;

template <typename E>
class binarySearchTree: binaryTreeInterface<E>{
public:

int LessThan<E>(E itm1, E itm2) {
  if (itm1 < itm2) {return -1;}
  else if (itm1 > itm2) {return 1;}
  else if (itm1 == itm2) {return 0;}
}


int LessThan<string>(string s1, string s2) { 
  return strcmp(s1, s2);
}

void AddNode(E itm) {
    /* ... */
    if (LessThan(itm, v[i]) <= 0) {i = LeftChild(i);} // v[i] is a variable E 
    else if (LessThan(itm, v[i]) > 0) {i = RightChild(i);}
}
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
In file included from test_binarySearchTree.cpp:1:0:
binarySearchTree.h:26:9: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
     int Compare<E>(E itm1, E itm2) {
         ^

binarySearchTree.h:26:16: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
     int Compare<E>(E itm1, E itm2) {
                ^

test_binarySearchTree.cpp:78:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 }
 ^

In file included from test_binarySearchTree.cpp:1:0:
binarySearchTree.h:24:5: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
     }
```

Comment: Also just so you know, there's other stuff inside AddNode using variables like v and i but I omitted them since I think theyre irrelevant. The main thing is I'm wondering how to properly overload LessThan so that whenever strings are used as parameters it does the second implementation shown rather then the first

Comment: `std::string` supports a complete set of comparison operators so your functions don't need to be specialised for strings at all.   There is also a set of `compare()` member functions that do almost exactly what you're trying to do when specialising for strings.   Your `LessThan` function also does not check the relationship "less than", so probably needs a different name.  It would also pay to post actual code rather than code which is inconsistent with the error messages.

Comment: SUre, here's the entire code. Everything past addnode is most likely irrevelant, but here it is: https://codeshare.io/G6xnyQ

Comment: that's not what I meant.   Firstly, the code you're writing is unnecessary, since `std::string` provides exactly that functionality.  Second, the code you showed in the post here has no templated function named `Compare` but the error messages which, you claim, are associated with that code, report concerns with a templated function named `Compare` - providing conflicting information in your questions is not an effective way to get useful answers.

Comment: @Keeyan -- What if the user wants to compare pointer values?  A better implementation is for the user to provide an optional comparison function in `AddNode`, and to not have you figure out how to compare two types if the comparison is different than using the normal `<` operator.  That's how the STL alogrithms work.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't work with addstring, before I just had the comparison stuff there as usual (if (itm <= v[i]) {...}) but it gave me wrong results. I talked to my TA and he said this is the proper way of doing it, I just have no idea how to properly implement a function that overloads itself when given a string. Also about the compare thing, thats my bad, I changed the function name from "Compare" to "LessThan" and forgot to recompile it. So Compare is just IsLess. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Keeyan *I talked to my TA and he said this is the proper way of doing it*  -- Your TA needs to look at the STL algorithm functions such as `std::sort` to see how this is done.

Comment: Ok, so in that case is it ok if you just tell me the proper way to overload a function like this so it takes strings rather then E whenever it's used with a string if you know how? I understand that the assignment's really weird but I'm positive the TA is telling me the way the instructor wanted me to do it, so if I just have that information I think it'll work even though its like a really inefficient way of doing things. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Keeyan -- I don't know why they teach creating classes this way.  To amend what I stated, the `binarySearchTree` template itself should have an optional second parameter that tells `binarySearchTree` how to sort.  It would default to `LessThan` but will use the function / functor provided by the user when a comparison needs to be done.  That is the way to do this -- what if I want a `binarySearchTree` of `foo` types, and you have no idea how to compare a `foo`, thus not know what to write as an overload?  The user should provide the comparitor.

Comment: That makes so much more sense to me, but unfortunately that's not an option since they will be testing it with their own main file, and as far as I know they won't be calling the constructor for binarySearchTree with the function. But isn't it possible for them to manually overload the operators for whatever classes they use, and that will allow for it to use the non-string LessThan function?

Comment: @Keeyan -- Yes, they can provide the necessary operator, and then `LessThan` will work.  Also, note that the class need only provide `<` and `==`, as `>` can be derived from `<`.  So your `LessThan` function can be improved to not directly use `<`.   Also, if they feed a type into `binarySearchTree` that does not satisfy those requirements, then the compiler will tell them.  If then they say no, I just say "enter the real world" -- many C++ algorithms and classes require the types to be used to satisfy certain criteria.  That's a good thing, not a bad thing.

Comment: Also, C++ uses `strict-weak-order`, where the comparison either returns `true` or `false` when the two values are compared, not the tri-value return of `-1`, `0`, and `1`.  If that's the case, all the class need to provided is an overloaded `<` operator.  That's why your assignment given to you originally has flaws in terms of what's really done in C++.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for all the helpful information!

Comment: Should have stated "So your `LessThan` function can be improved to not directly use `>`*.  But the issue would be that if the type is a pointer,  pointer types cannot be overloaded -- this is where the user would have to provide a replacement for `LessThan`, unless the user really wants to insert pointers depending on the pointer value.  So the approach the C++ standard library takes is both -- if the type contains overloaded `<`, then it's used -- if the type doesn't have  an overloaded `<` but the user provides a comparitor function, that's used.